# Kotlin : How to access private data members of class by their objects?

Tags: kotlin

How do I access p.name by its object if it private?

Getter and setter don't work here.

```
class Person(f_name : String, l_name : String){
    private var name = f_name + l_name
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
    private var age : Int? = null
        get() {
            println("Age getter")
            return field
        }
        set(value) {
            println("Age setter")
            field = value
        }
    constructor(f_name: String, l_name: String, age : Int):this(f_name, l_name){
        name = "Mr./Msr./Ms. $f_name $l_name"
        this.age = age
    }

}

fun main() {
    var p = Person("M", "M")
    var m = Person("P", "P", 20)

    println("p : Person(${p.name})") // Shows error here

}
```

I cannot access any private member in this way.
There is no use of getter and setter here.

Comment: *How do I access p.name by its object if it private?* - you don't. Getters and setters are not implicitly public. What result were you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to approach this with an immutable data class. Then setters are unnecessary and getters can be public:

```
data class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int? = null
)
```

The complete name you could define as an extension property then:

```
val Person.name get() = "Mr./Msr./Ms. $firstName $lastName"
```

As a default private properties are not accessible, but you can restrict access of a setter if you like:

```
var name: String = ""
    private set
```

In general a property is a getter and maybe a setter accessing a field. The field is never public. Therefore to achieve what you want, you only need to declare the property as `var name: String`.

Comment: Ya, I found about that.

But I'm asking that i want to keep the data member as private only and make getter and setter.

Both getter and setter working.

Comment: In that case you just make the property public. It's not like in _Java_: You don't have to manage the visibility of the field yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Remove private from property and set it to accessor. It will make it visile to other classes as readonly property whereas can only be set with in its own class.

```
var name = f_name + l_name
    private set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```